# pass value with a link and use it in php

Tags: php, html

I am learning PHP and trying to make one admin panel. I have a link like below in my table.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_form_vertical"class="list-icons-item"><i class="icon-eye"></i></a>
```

when clicking on the above link icon, it's opening one modal form, in that form I want to show all details of user of that row id from the table. I have my modal code and PHP code like below

```
    <div id="modal_form_vertical" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">


        <?php
        $users1_qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 1";
        $result1=mysqli_query($mysqli,$users1_qry);
        $row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

        ?>
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                        <h5 class="modal-title">More Details</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>

                    <form action="#">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Username</label>
                                        <input type="text" value = "<?php echo $row1['username'];?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Email</label>
                                        <input type="text" value = "<?php echo $row1['email'];?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Full Name</label>
                                        <input type="text" value = "<?php echo $row1['name'];?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Address</label>
                                        <input type="text" value = "<?php echo $row1['address'];?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Phone</label>
                                        <input type="text" value = "<?php echo $row1['phone'];?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Pin</label>
                                        <input type="text" value = "<?php echo $row1['pin'];?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Gender</label>
                                        <input type="text" value = "<?php if($row1['gender'] ==0){echo 'Male';} else{echo 'Female';};?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Occupation</label>
                                        <input type="text" value = "<?php if($row1['occupation'] ==0){echo 'Parent';} else{echo 'Teacher';};?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Corporation Id</label>
                                        <input type="text" value = "<?php echo $row1['corp'];?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                                        <label>Password</label>
                                        <input type="text" value = "<?php echo $row1['password'];?>" class="form-control" disabled>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You can see currently I have used 1 as user id in my mysqli query because I don't know how I can I pass row id to this modal class and so I can retrieve and use it. Let me know if someone can help me for same.

Thanks

Comment: You retrieve data dyamically using XHR (Ajax.) Too broad a topic for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the ID by using POST or GET method, save it in the variable in your script and then use in the sql query.

**Example:**

```
 <?php
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $users1_qry="SELECT * FROM users WHERE id =".$id;
    $result1=mysqli_query($mysqli,$users1_qry);
    $row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);

 ?>
```

Consider using prepare/execute method so that you prevent possible SQL injections.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: I know it but during link click form does not have any action as well its not submit link, then How we can post request?

Comment: if you don't specify the action and leave it like " ", then it will direct to the same script. You need to decied which method you need to send the form with. Its either method="POST" or method="GET".

Comment: Also in inputs, there must be name added so that you can refer to it later when assigning the $_POST['id']

Comment: I don't have any form with link, its simple table where I have above link.

Comment: Two questions: 1) what is the desired result after clicking the link? 2) do you want to pass some information to the database table when clicking the link?

Comment: I have table in which I am displaying user information. I have link for view more details of that user. When click on that link, I am opening modal view where I want display full details of that user. But I have not idea how I can pass id with that link click and retrive it so I can make query for that user id

Comment: Can pass it by form using GET method. Please design the link in a way similar to: somelink.com?id=10   by that you can pass the proper id and use it as a reference to your sql query.